# How to include more than one class while fetching from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, datacontext

I want to include two classes while fetching.  I know how to do this with one class but I am not sure how to do it with two.

Here I am including Student

```
var service = dc.service.Include("Student").OrderBy(i => i.id);
```

I am not sure how to add both Student and Program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just chain multiple `Include` methods.

```
var service = dc.service.Include("Student").Include("Program").OrderBy(i => i.id);
```